# VSPerfReport: exclusive time equal to inclusive time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, profiling

I am profiling C++ using an instrumenting profiler from Microsoft (VSPerf) and converting the .vsp report file to .csv using VSPerfReport. In Report_FunctionSummary.csv the exclusive and inclusive times are the same for functions which do call other functions in the same object file. Is this a known problem and how can it be solved? I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Inclusive time is exclusive time plus time in callees. So if a routine has no callees, inclusive time equals exclusive time. It will also be equal if the routine did call other routines but the profiler could not see those other routines.

Comment: It did call other routines from the same object file. Why couldn't the VS profiler see it? Does it only see public functions?

Comment: I have got the same issue ! quant_dev have you resolve this issue? See other function in the report?